# Border parameter does not show a color,but enabledBorder parameter does

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]Can anyone simply explain the difference between border and enabledBorder.When I give OutlineInputBorder to both of them and set a color inside of BorderSide class.Single border does not show anything,but enabled does.Actually before me someone had asked this question,but I could not get the point.Can someone simply expain it to me?

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet, there are 6 type of borders for textFormFiled

Comment: Yeah I shared screenshoot of the code.I have commented the parts in my code

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/10157127)

Comment: Thank you so much Sir.Up until today I did not know it.For the next time I will take into account it.

Answer (score 1):

Border is used as an emergency solution if none of the various borders (e.g. enabled or disabled) has been set.

**From the docs:**

This property is only used when the appropriate one of errorBorder, focusedBorder, focusedErrorBorder, disabledBorder, or enabledBorder is not specified. This border's InputBorder.borderSide property is configured by the InputDecorator, depending on the values of InputDecoration.errorText, InputDecoration.enabled, InputDecorator.isFocused and the current Theme.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/border.html

Now to the question why it doesn't change the color, if you just set the border parameter. It adopts the colours from the theme that were stored by default. Therefore you have to overwrite the theme.

```
 theme: ThemeData(
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
           borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.pink)
        )
    ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir.It is so clear for me now.